# Download images from url in order

Tags: c#, image, url, download

I am getting html source and parsing it. After that, i want to download images. i download them. But sometimes not downloading. Because i couldnt use thread or parallel programming which i need, i dont know. My source is:

```
foreach(var pic in pics)
        {
            try { 
             client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadFileCompleted);
                client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(pic.Attributes[cmbAttr.Text].Value), folder + "\\" + picid.ToString() + ".jpg");

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500); // I wrote sleep code, because i dont know parallel programming. But sometimes it is not downloading in 1500 milisecond.

            picid++;
            }catch(Exception err)
            {
                label8.Text=(err.Message.ToString());
                continue;
            }
        }
```

this is my code. i want to download the pictures in order. 1.jpg, 2.jpg etc. i download it too. But sometimes it is getting error. Because another download starting while last download before finished. I want to start after finish last download. My english is bad. I hope i tell it true. 
Thanks for help.

Comment: Then stop downloading them asynchronously

Comment: Remove `client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadFileCompleted);` out of for loop. You don't need `pics.length` eventhandlers. Add it somewhere where you attach it once.

Comment: After 1500ms you start a new task for download. You do not need the Sleep if you a) await the download task or b) call client.DownloadFile wich will return when completed

Comment: Thanks. I wrote an async void.
 private async void downloadimage(string url,string folder)
        {
            client.DownloadFile(new Uri(url), folder);
        }
And it is getting images very well. Thanks a lot. 
I was thinking it must be downloadasyncfile... 

Have a good day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadFileCompleted);

foreach(var pic in pics)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(Object state =>
    {

        var data = (dynamic)state;
        Int32 id = (Int32)state.Id;
        Picture picture = (Picture)state.Picture;

        client.DownloadFile(new Uri(picture.Attributes[cmbAttr.Text].Value), folder + "\\" + id.ToString() + ".jpg")

    }, new { Id = picid, Picture = pic });

    ++picid;
}
```